# Display image from base64 code of api response

Tags: php, json, base64

Iam trying to execute an api. Its response will be an image in base64 code.

API working fine and Iam not getting image. Tried few methods but not worked.

**API response sample:**

{"status":"success","message":"Success","base64":"data:image/png;base64,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"}

**Full Code I tried:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Generate QR Code</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><b>QR Code Test</b></p>               
                <form id="frm" method="post" role="form">               
                                <label for="channel"> Select Portal:</label>
                                <select id="api_url" name="api_url">
                                    <option value="app2" selected>https://app2</option>
                                </select>
                                    <br>
                                    Access Token: 
                                    <input id="access_token" type="text" name="access_token" class="form-control">
                                    <br>
                                    Instance ID:
                                    <input id="instance_id" type="text" name="instance_id" class="form-control">
                                    <br>            
                                <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Generate QR Code">
                            </form> 

                            <p>
                            <hr>
                            Result 1:  <br> <br>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])){ //check if form was submitted
$access_token = $_POST['access_token'];
$instance_id = $_POST['instance_id'];
$api_url = $_POST['api_url'];
$ch=curl_init('https://'.$api_url.'/api/get_qrcode?instance_id='.$instance_id.'&access_token='.$access_token.'');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$imagecode = json_decode($data, true);
echo $imagecode->base64;
}
?>
                            </p>
                            <hr>
                                    <strong>QR Code:</strong> <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <p id="qrcode" name="qrcode">   
                                    <img src="<?php echo $imagecode->base64; ?>" >
    
                                    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Getting this error for** $imagecode->base64
" Notice: Trying to get property 'base64' of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\wappapi-qrcode\index2.php on line 37 "

Need to extract "base64" part from response and show it as image.
I expect $imagecode to show base64 part of API response. (API Response sample given above).

Don't need to save images. Just need to show image when api submitted.
 
I request your help to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: What does echoing $imagecode->base64 return? I suspect the issue might be in invalid base64

Comment: Getting this error for $imagecode->base64 " Notice: Trying to get property 'base64' of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\wappapi-qrcode\index2.php on line 37 "

Comment: Why is this tagged with Javascript, but does not contain any such code? Also, why not dump `$imagecode` to inspect what it contains?

Comment: I think $imagecode to show base64 part of API response. (API Response sample given above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option for the cURL request, without it cURL will just return true or false based on if the request failed or not.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])){ //check if form was submitted
    $access_token = $_POST['access_token'];
    $instance_id = $_POST['instance_id'];
    $api_url = $_POST['api_url'];
    $ch=curl_init('https://'.$api_url.'/api/get_qrcode?instance_id='.$instance_id.'&access_token='.$access_token.'');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $imagecode = json_decode($data, true);
    echo $imagecode->base64;
  }
?>
```

You can read more about how the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option affects the curl_exec() results [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)